# Error in sending data from background.js to popup.js in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, background, popup, content-script

I am creating a chrome extension. In that I am getting problem in sending message from background.js to popup.js.  I am successfull in sending some static data from background.js to popup.js. But, when I try to send data dynamically (i.e. the data sent to background.js by content-script.js) from background.js to popup.js, it is giving undefined as I print it on popup.html.

This is my popup.js:

```
 var value;
  window.onload = function(){   
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({getVal: "Hi"}, function(response){
    value = response.responseSeltext;
    alert(value);
    });
    document.getElementById('save').onclick = test;
}
```

This is my background.js:

```
    var seltext;
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

        if (request.ezynotes != ""){
          seltext = request.ezynotes;
          alert("In extension "+seltext);

          //document.getElementById("notes").innerHTML += request.ezynotes;
         }
        if (request.getVal != ""){
          sendResponse({responseSeltext:seltext});

          //seltext = request.ezynotes;
          alert("In extension "+seltext);

          //document.getElementById("notes").innerHTML += request.ezynotes;
         }

  });
```

Comment: Can you please _not_ use `alert()` for debugging? It steals focus from your popup and might make it close. Also, it is known to cause problems due to blocking execution.

Comment: I tried by removing all alerts, but still it is giving undefined on popup.html.

Comment: How are you testing that it is undefined? Also, please try to debug by right-clicking on the extension button and selecting "Inspect popup", if you haven't already.

Answer (score -2):

I m assuming u r listening for message in background from content.js and trying to send it to popup.js. Right??In that case u have to send message from background and add a listening event in popup.js which is not present in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I am listening for message in background from content.js and trying to send it to popup.js. It is correct. I think listening to message in popup.js is one way and other way is what I have written - i.e. the response which will come from background.js. I have verified by just sending static data ("Hi") from background.js to popup.js, but I am unable to get this dynamic data.

Comment: @RSY In background.js seltext is not defined thats the reason u r getting undefined. In javascript global variables default value is undefined.